# Overlay each frame from a video file into one final image

Tags: c++, opencv

I created a program that changes the color of each pixel in a video file in grayscale.

Now every frame of this video should be superimposed on each other and saved as one final image, where every frame transition is visible. Does anyone know how to do this? (Used with C ++ and opencv).

Thank you in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int, char**)

{
cv::VideoCapture cap("/MyVideo.avi");
cv::Mat frame;

if( !cap.isOpened() )
    throw "Error when reading Video.avi";

for( ; ; )
 {
    cap >> frame;
    if(frame.empty())
        break;

    for( int i = 0; i < frame.rows; i++ )
                      for( int j = 0; j < frame.cols; j++ )

                          {
                              float R = frame.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0];
                              float G = frame.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1];
                              float B = frame.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2];
                              float Y = 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B;


                              frame.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[0] = Y;
                              frame.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[1] = Y;
                              frame.at<Vec3b>(i,j)[2] = Y;

                          }

    imshow("MyVideo.avi", frame);
    if (cv::waitKey(1) >= 0)
    break;
 }
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Instead of nested for loops, you can simply use `cv::cvtColor(img, img, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);` and then `cv::cvtColor(img, img, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);`

Comment: @ZdaR: Yes, I know, but I need to repaint every pixel. And this task is completed, and now I need to do the second part of this task, because I have problem with it.

Comment: Can you please explain the expected output? Suppose we have a video with 5 colored frames, and we converted each frame to Gray-scale, Now what would be the output? A video with 5 gray frames? or a video with 10 frames (colored and gray scale interleaved) or some other combination ?

Comment: @ZdaR: We need to take each frame from the video file and put all these video frames in one image so that as a result we can see all the transitions between frames. Color is not important (gray or color image), I do not understand how to solve the problem with such an overlay.

Comment: Sounds like you maybe want to calculate a per-pixel mean of all the frames. Not sure how useful that will be, but other than that I can't really envision what you could concievably have in mind.

Comment: @DanMašek: I need to make a long exposure effect just like in this photo. [link](http://www.blogbaster.org/i/i402/1112/bb/0979affc2304.jpg)

Comment: For creating an effect such as exposure, I think a lot of things depend upon camrea hardware. I am not sure if you can create an exposure effect out of a given video? Have you looked out for some implementations or some research paper ?

Comment: @PELMYACH just use the `qt-creator` tag when the problem is relative to the IDE, in your case it has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @eyllanesc: I just work in Qt-Creator.

Comment: @PELMYACH if we follow your logic, you do not think that all SO questions would have as a label the most popular editors. You must use the Qt-Creator tag when the problem is in Qt-Creater, for example: "Qt Creator autocomplete does not work", etc.

Comment: @eyllanesc: okay.

Comment: Hmm, maybe something akin to taking the maximum value of each pixel? It would be handy if you could provide some sample video you want to apply this on.